# modify getRouteKeyName in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, routes, slug

I defined slug for single DB in a column of structure DB. When I will call the slug in route, Could I get slug from another model (e.g. structure here) in route?

The route is:

```
localhost:8000/api/singles/firstTest
```

I defined getRouteKeyName function in Single model:

```
public function structure()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Structure::class);
    }

public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return $this->structure()->select('slug')->first();
    }
```

Comment: So you mean the `firstTest` part of your, you need to match it with  the database row and get slug of it? Can you elaborate mode whats `firstTest` and what do you want to get?

Comment: `firstTest` is a unique slug for a row of single table which is store is structure table. when the route has `firstTest`, I wanna call its id from single table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you will get the  `firstTest` as route param if you have specified route as  :

`Route::get('api/singles/{slug}', 'SomeController@someAction');`

Then controller :

```
public function someAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    // Perform validations and policy authorization if required

    $id = Single::whereHas('structure', function ($query) use($slug) {
        $query->where('slug', '=', $slug);
    })->first();

    if(!$id){
        abort(404);
    }

    // Process the data using $id obtained above
}
```

Comment: Whats `Single $single` as the first argument in code you have mentioned now? Is it a dependency injection? Because if it is then it will not have `->id` on it directly. Also can you show your route declaration please?

Comment: This is my route: `Route::apiResource('/tournaments/{tournament}/singles/{slug}', 'Tournament\Structure\SingleController');`

Comment: and what is `{tournament}`?I mean does it have any significance in finding this id you need?

Comment: Can you post the structure of your db for these tables, now its kinda hard to guess

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I am using apiResource and this way wont work.

Comment: apiResource will not matter as long as your are getting what you want in the url routes. But I hope you figure the solution soon :)